# ClassCastException in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I have recently added a new column (age) to a database table (user). I am using MS Sql server.

I have a java app that is trying to add a new record to this table. The app uses Hibernate to update the table.

I have a POJO called UserModel. The age column is of type int.

My model is defined as follows:

```
@NotEmpty
@Column(name = "Age", nullable = false, precision = 10)
public Integer getAge() {
    return Age;
}

public void setAge(Integer Age) {
    this.Age = Age;
}

@Transient
public boolean isAgeSet() {
    return getAge() != null;
}
```

When I try to enter a row, I get the following error message:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer
at org.hibernate.validator.NotEmptyValidator.isValid(NotEmptyValidator.java:36)
```

The age is set in Java code as 12345.

Has anyone any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`@NotEmpty` can only be used for `String` or `Collection` type properties.

See [API documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/4.1/api/org/hibernate/validator/constraints/NotEmpty.html).

You are already using `nullable = false`. That should be enough.